# Trying to change individual letters of text when clicked on using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently failed a coding challenge but have been trying to complete it anyways for future knowledge. I am trying to change the individual letters of text when clicked on by the user using JavaScript/jQuery. There are a few steps that have to come before this happens. I have all the steps below working except for step number '3'.

**Directions:**

1.) Hovering a cursor on or below a word causes a underline bar to appear.
 
2.) Clicking on a word when bar is present displays new block with word in it.
3.) The color of each letter is changed by clicking on each letter. Each letter must change before next step can be implemented.
4.)Clicking on the highlighted word highlights the word to 'orange'.
5.) Clicking on the highlighted word again will change the color to 'red'.
6.)Clicking on the highlighted word again will reset the word.

Below I have implemented some pseudo-code into the `index.js` file for what I think would logically work, but am not too sure how to go about configuring it together:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="word_div">
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">It's</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">no</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">use</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">going</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">back</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">to</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">yesterday</span></p>,
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">because</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">I</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">was</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">a</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">different</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">person</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style">then</span></p>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.default_word_style {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline;
}

.default_word_style:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: orange;
}

.inner_default_word_style {
  color: black;
}

.inner_default_word_style:hover {
 color: black;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bold_orange {
  color: orange;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.purple {
  color: purple;
}

.added_word {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.display_none {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  counter = 0;
  var word = '';
  $('.inner_default_word_style').click(function(){
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 1){
      word = $(event.target).html();
      $(event.target).append('<div class="added_word">' + word + '</div>');
      } else if (counter == 2){

        // 1.) When a letter is clicked, change its 'color' to 'purple'.

        // 2.) Check the string in which the letter is in to see if all the
        //     letters of that string have been clicked on.

        // 3.) IF all the letters in that string HAVE been clicked, 'counter += 1'
        //     so that the next click has a 'counter' = '3'.

        //     ELSE

        // 4.) IF all the letters have NOT been clicked on, 'counter -= 1'
        //     so that the next click has a 'counter' = '2' again. Repeat steps 1-3.


      } else if (counter == 3){
      $(".added_word").remove();
      $(event.target).addClass('bold_orange');
      }else if (counter == 4){
      $(event.target).addClass('red');
      } else if (counter == 5){
      $(event.target).removeClass('red bold_orange');
      counter = 0;
    }
    console.log(counter);
  });
});
```

**Also, would I need to put tags around each individual letter to target that letter when clicked?**

Comment: can you place your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: For a start, you will need one counter per word.

Comment: @HarshSanghani: https://jsfiddle.net/46vds67p/1/

Comment: Interaction between clicking a letter and clicking a word is not clear. The pseudo-code indicates functionality not stated in the intro.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: So does that mean I will have to create a conditional statement for each individual word directing it to add 1 to the counter every time it is clicked on?

Comment: As far as i can see, you will have to treat each letter individually,for your '3rd point problem'... You can put them in span or something.

Comment: You have to take each latter within some tag so then you can perform action on each letter by clicking or etc..

Comment: Harsh and Ajit: I have tried doing both of those things. The problem is when I put tags around the individual letters, it messes with the CSS for when the entire word is clicked, it will only target the letter. I have not figured how to get around this.

Comment: I think that counter(s) are a bad idea. It's probably better to detect the state of words by looking at which classes are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go. I split the words into spans then bound them with the click event.

Currently this is steps 1 and 3,4,5,6.

I don't not understand step 2.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tar > p').each(function(index, word) {
    word = $(word);

    var originalText = word.text();
    var newText = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < originalText.length; i++) {
      newText += '<span>' + originalText[i] + '</span>';
    }

    word.html(newText);

    word.hover(function() {
      word.addClass('underline');
    }, function() {
      word.removeClass('underline');
    });

    word.find('span').each(function(index, letter) {
      letter = $(letter);

      letter.click(function(e) {
        if (word.hasClass('wordstage2') || word.hasClass('wordstage1')) return;
        letter.addClass('colorText');
      });
    });

    word.click(function() {
      if (word.hasClass('wordstage2')) {
        word.removeClass('wordstage2');
      } else if (word.hasClass('wordstage1')) {
        word.removeClass('wordstage1');
        word.addClass('wordstage2');
      } else if (word.children().length == word.children(".colorText").length) {
        word.find('span').each(function(index, letter) {
          letter = $(letter);
          letter.removeClass('colorText');
        });

        word.addClass('wordstage1');
      }

    })
  });
});
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.colorText {
  color: blue;
}
.wordstage1 {
  color: orange;
}
.wordstage2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tar">
    <p>It's<p/> 
    <p>no<p/> 
    <p>use<p/> 
    <p>going<p/> 
    <p>back<p/> 
    <p>to<p/> 
    <p>yesterday<p/>, 
    <p>because<p/> 
    <p>I<p/> 
    <p>was<p/> 
    <p>a<p/> 
    <p>different<p/> 
    <p>person<p/> 
    <p>then<p/>. 
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. It gave me the following output for step number 3 using the logic that first needs to be considered: "It'sIt's no use going back to yesterday, because I was a different person then."

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 I'm afraid i don't understand what your saying. :S In relation to your comment what is "It"?

Comment: I changed it from hello world to your original text if that s what you mean :)?

Comment: I apologize. This solved the issue. I originally placed the code in the area where the pseudo code was. Thank you.

Comment: Ahh ok no worries haha you confused me a bit. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need one counter per word, than you can achieve this, i use id for this in your code.

```js
$(function(){
  counter = 0;
  var Elementcounter = {}; // to handle counter for each element
  var word = '';
  $('.inner_default_word_style').click(function(event){
   
      if(!isNaN(Elementcounter[event.target.id])){  
           Elementcounter[event.target.id] += 1;
     }else{
           Elementcounter[event.target.id] = 1;
     }
    counter =  Elementcounter[event.target.id]

    if (counter == 1){
      word = $(event.target).html();
      $(event.target).append('<div class="added_word">' + word + '</div>');
      } else if (counter == 2){

        // 1.) When a letter is clicked, change its 'color' to 'purple'.

        // 2.) Check the string in which the letter is in to see if all the
        //     letters of that string have been clicked on.

        // 3.) IF all the letters in that string HAVE been clicked, 'counter += 1'
        //     so that the next click has a 'counter' = '3'.

        //     ELSE

        // 4.) IF all the letters have NOT been clicked on, 'counter -= 1'
        //     so that the next click has a 'counter' = '2' again. Repeat steps 1-3.


      } else if (counter == 3){
      $(".added_word").remove();
      $(event.target).addClass('bold_orange');
      }else if (counter == 4){
      $(event.target).addClass('red');
      } else if (counter == 5){
      $(event.target).removeClass('red bold_orange purple');
      counter = 0;
    }
    console.log(counter);
  });
      });
```

```css
.default_word_style {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline;
}

.default_word_style:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: orange;
}

.inner_default_word_style {
  color: black;
}

.inner_default_word_style:hover {
 color: black;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  background-color: purple;
}

.bold_orange {
  color: orange;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.purple {
  color: purple;
}

.added_word {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.display_none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word_div">
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style" id="e1">It's</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style" id="e2" >no</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e3" >use</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e4" >going</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e5" >back</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e6" >to</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e7" >yesterday</span></p>,
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e8" >because</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e9">I</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e10">was</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style"  id="e11" >a</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style" id="e12" >different</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style" id="e13" >person</span></p>
      <p class="default_word_style"><span class="inner_default_word_style" id="e14" >then</span></p>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the possibile advantage that cyclic color changes are defined in an array that can be added to.

```
var wordColors = ['black', 'bold_orange', 'red'];
var clss = { 'highlight':'purple' , 'dummy':'dummy' };

// Wrap all words in `<span class="word">....</span>`
var str = $('.word_div').text().split(/\s/).map(function(word) {
    return '<span class="word ' + wordColors[0] + '">' + word + '</span>';
});
$('.word_div').html(str.join(' '));

$('span.word').each(function(i, word) {
    // Wrap all letters in `<span class="letter">.</span>`
    var $word = $(word);
    var letters = $word.text().split('');
    str = letters.map(function(letter) {
        return '<span class="letter">' + letter + '</span>';
    });
    $word.html(str.join(''));
    str.length = 0;
}).on('click', function() {
    $word = $(this);
    $("#currentWord").text($word.text());
    var $letters = $word.find("span.letter");
    if($letters.not('.'+clss.highlight).not('.'+clss.dummy).length === 0) {
        $letters.off('click').removeClass(clss.highlight).addClass(clss.dummy);
        $.each(wordColors, function(i, color) {
            if($word.hasClass(color)) {
                var colorIndex = (i + 1) % wordColors.length;
                $word.removeClass(color).addClass(wordColors[colorIndex]);
                if(colorIndex === 0) {
                    $letters.removeClass(clss.dummy).on('click', letterClick); // reset
                }
                return false; // break
            }
        });
    }
});
function letterClick() {
    $(this).addClass(clss.highlight);
}
$('span.letter').on('click', letterClick);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46vds67p/2/

Try adding, say, 'green' to `wordColors`, and a corresponding CSS directive.